# How do i select element by xpath using another, already selected as root in python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath

I need to select all the points in specific svg graph. There are six svg's on page, sharing same class, having no id, etc, so I have no way to distinguish them in xpath. I tried following code, which is not working.

```
for svg in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']"):
    for circle in svg.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='circle']"):
        print(circle)
```

any idea how to do it?

Python 3.6, Selenium 3.141.0, Firefox Webdriver

Comment: Use `.` which will identify the child elements of the parent.

    `for circle in svg.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[name()='circle']"): `

Comment: Oh, that simple. Now i feel ashamed for even asking.
Thank you!